# How long a time limit should we set on meals for 6yr old very slow eater?

Tags: primary-schooler, eating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my child eat so slowly?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/why-does-my-child-eat-so-slowly)

Very slow distracted procrastinating eater. Going to start time limits this weekend, but how long for say a sandwich or bowl of cereal and how much longer for a roast dinner?

We will explain what we are going to do before we start it. What do parents think about how to go about it - five minute warning before time is up, or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would not make a table of "X minutes of time allowed for eating food Y" because that sounds like *working on the symptoms* rather than looking at the actual cause.

There are already several related questions with some answers that might be useful to you:

- [How do I get an easily distracted 5 year old to eat more?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/how-do-i-get-an-easily-distracted-5-year-old-to-eat-more)
- [Why does my child eat so slowly?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/why-does-my-child-eat-so-slowly)
- [How can I encourage my 4.5 year old daughter to eat without needing tons of time along with play?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/how-can-i-stop-my-4-5yr-old-daughter-from-playing-while-eating)

Most of the answers have one thing in common: Decide in advance how long the entire meal should take, and when the time is up, move on to the next activity in the day (or evening). Yes, the child will most likely still be hungry: that experience only needs a few repetitions before the lesson is learned. Don't worry, this won't hurt the child if it's just a couple of times.